# How do I modify the system print method?

Tags: r, oop

The default `R` print method for a `glm` (`print.glm`) reports *Null Deviance* and *Residual Deviance* but not the relative size of the latter as a part of the former, which is, IMO, more relevant to evaluating the model fit than the absolute values.

I want to modify the method to make it print the relative deviance.
E.g., right now `R` prints:

```
Degrees of Freedom: 36 Total (i.e. Null);  35 Residual
Null Deviance:      182.8 
Residual Deviance: 10.22    AIC: 63.39
```

I want it to print

```
Degrees of Freedom: 36 Total (i.e. Null);  35 Residual
Null Deviance:      182.8 
Residual Deviance: 10.22    AIC: 63.39 
Relative Residual Deviance: 5.59%
```

(NB: I know how to compute and pretty print the number!)

Different systems provide different facilities for that; e.g., `Emacs` has *hooks* and CLOS MOP has [`after`-methods](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/07_fb.htm), but I don't know how to do that in `R`.

How do I do that in `R`? Does `R` have method qualifiers at all?

Thanks!

PS. I do not want to explicitly edit system code, and I do not want to copy and modify it either: when the next version of `R` is released, I do not want to have to edit my code to incorporate the improvements made to the system `print.glm`.

Comment: So you want to "modify the system print method" but you don't want to modify the print method? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: this question is unclear. Please add an example. what is the actual print, and what do you expect/want to have.

Comment: @ndoogan: I do want to modify system behavior, but I do not want to edit system source code. This is routine in object-oriented systems and is usually accomplished by before/after/around methods.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will be interested to know if such a solution (i.e. an alternative to re-specifying the print method) exists. Though, I think this specific example is a simple modification, and print.glm probably virtually never changes from version to version of R.

Comment: @sds and stupidly simple at that (but still worth seeing). Thanks for the notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, it turned out to be simple:

```
print.glm.system <- print.glm
print.glm <- function(glm, ...) { 
  print.glm.system(glm, ...)
  cat("Relative Residual Deviance: ",100*glm$deviance/glm$null.deviance,"%\n") 
  invisible(glm)
}
```

PS. This is not an infinite loop because `print.glm.system` contains the original "system" function **object**.